# sftp batch file not able to execute

Tags: ftp, sftp

I have a windows batch file to connect from Server A (Windows) to 
Server B (UNIX) via sftp to get a file. The script is as below:

```
sftpg3 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oIdentityFile=EAPIINSTADM_hostnameA ftpeapsg@hostnameB
lcd D:\APPBASE\EAPSG\GEMSSG
get GENUOBGW1 /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG
exit
```

When I run the script it stops after running the first line i.e sftpg3 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no...

```
D:\APPBASE\EAPSG\GEMSSG>sftpg3 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oIdentityFile=EAPIINSTADM_hostnameA ftpeapsg@hostnameB
Warning: ignoring unsupported option -o
Warning: ignoring unsupported option -o
Remote system type is POSIX.
sftp>
```

It didn't execute below lines:

```
lcd D:\APPBASE\EAPSG\GEMSSG
get GENUOBGW1 /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG
```

If I run the command manually one line at a time it works.

Any idea why the script does not run completely?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's because sftpg3 is a sftp like client which prompt an interactive session with the server waiting for input. so your first line in the script just opens the session and wait until that command (which is the prompt opened) to exit. you need to redirect the input into that prompted session (in unix like using <<) I don't know how it is done in windows. but if the aim from writing that script is to copy a file from the server you can just use [scpg3](https://www.ssh.com/manuals/client-user/61/scpg3.html)